# Sync icon in every file or folder after uninstall overgrive

Tags: icons, sync

I need to know how to find the script or directive which add a "sync" icon in every file and folder I synced with overgrive. After I uninstalled overgrive, the icons remain.

[image]

I want to delete that green "sync" icon from the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, very annoying. I fixed it by using Déjà Dup Backup Tool, backed up the folder with annoying icon to my Google drive, deleted it from my computer. Then restored it from my Google drive using Deja Dup. All the icons were removed from every folder. Hope it helps! Also Deja Dup is a great backup tool!